# iOS deployment target

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, deployment

IF I set the deployment target for my app to iOS 4.2 when submitting to app store, will users with iOS 3.2 (or anything below 4.2) be able to download and install the app and the app won't run or will they not be able to download and install the app itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They won't be able to install and run the app (until they upgrade the OS on their device to that of the Deployment Target or above).  But they might be able to buy and download the app using iTunes on their Mac or PC.

Answer (score 18):

No, that's exactly what deployment version is about.

Best practice is to build against latest SDK version, with deployment version as low as possible. But that requires the discipline to do runtime checks and fallback implementations whenever using a API that wasn't there yet in the deployment version.

Comment: What's the best way to find the minimum deployment iOS version possible for a RN project?

Comment: (What is RN?) The safest way to find out, is to test it: get a device or simulator with an older iOS version and just try to run your app.

Comment: RN == "React Native". My apologies.