# Can a iPad2 run App built on Xcode 4.2.1 iOS SDK 5

Tags: xcode, ios5

I have iPad 2 with 4.3.2, can I run an App built on xcode 4.2.1 ios sdk 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app's `IOS Deployment Target` is set to 4.3.2 or lower, then you should be fine.

If your app is built with `IOS Deployment Target` set to 5.0, it's likely not to be installable much less launchable on an iPad 2 running with iOS 4.3.2.

Also, [here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588309/ios-deployment-target).  You probably could have done a search for this before asking.  ;-)

Comment: thanks for you reply Michael Dautermann but how do I find IOS Deployment Target

Comment: It's a setting in your project's Build Settings. [Check out this Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html) and search for the words "Deployment Target" and this might give you helpful hints as to what's going on.

Comment: hi Michael Dautermann, once again thanks,but you see, I have MAC 10.7.1 with xcode 4.2.1... all the menu items have been changed from earlier xcode 3.5.
Im pretty much confused. not able to find build settings :(

Comment: [Check out this blog post](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-accessing-build-settings/), which shows how to go straight to build settings in XCode 4.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael Dautermann, Im pretty new to these ... and your help is highly appriciated.... it fixed... thanks thanks thanks