# How to ensure that we are not using latest SDK API?

Tags: ios, xcode

How to ensure that we are not using latest SDK API?

lets say you have iOs 5.0 SDK installed, but you are developing app for iOS 4.0, how can we ensure that we accidentally dont use any latest API that would break backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the right deployment target on Xcode and build against the latest SDK.

Search for **iOS Deployement Target** setting on Build Settings tab within PROJECTS -> YourName. This will also change that setting on TARGETS -> YourName.

For further reference see [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html).

As **hotpaw2** wrote in this [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588309/ios-deployment-target)

> They won't be able to install and run the app (until they upgrade the
>   OS on their device to that of the Deployment Target or above). But
>   they might be able to buy and download the app using iTunes on their
>   Mac or PC.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which is also not correct as i'm able to use MPNowPlayingInfoCenter while the MediaPlayer framework is linked as Required and the deployment target is set to 3.0 :) The app builds and naturally fails to start on iOS below 5.0

Comment: I have used these settings, still some times I end up using latest SDK. I hope there is some technique/trick with which xcode would show me warning or something like that

Comment: Apple doc is a good read.

it says..
* Not defined in the base SDK (for example, a symbol from a newer OS), you get a compile-time error.
* Defined in the base SDK but marked as deprecated, you get a compile-time warning.
* Defined in the deployment target, your code links and builds normally. At run time:

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set target's base sdk to iphone4 (3.2 on the screenshot) and build the project:
[image]

Comment: Setting the base sdk does not prevent to use a lower iOS. It allows only to compile the application with a lower SDK.