# How to mark an iPhone app iOS8 only?

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect

I'm working on an iPhone app that should be only available for `iOS 8+` users. How to make that work?

Comment: I believe that in developer page you can set it... I dont remember

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS deployment target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588309/ios-deployment-target)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the [deployment target](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW47) in the project editor.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to set right deployment target in the General options in XCode.

[image]

> The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system
>   version that your app can run on. For example, the lowest available
>   setting for iPad apps is iOS 4.3.

Source: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)