# If I am making an iOS app using a deployment target of 12.1, will that mean that the app does not support 10-?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

If by coding my app with the deployment target set as 12.1 will this mean that users using any iOS version previous to this would not be able to use the app?

**For more info go:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588309/ios-deployment-target?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,Your app will not support iOS 10, because deployment target is what the minimum iOS version should allow to run the app.

Let's say you have selected deployment target iOS 9, then your app will run on any device which has iOS greater than or equal to 9. It will not run on less than iOS 9.

In your case your app will not run on any device which has iOS less than 12.1.

So you should select deployment target as 9.

Comment: Looking at iOS distribution only .9% of users are on iOS 9 so I woudl say that 10 is where it shoudl eb from

Comment: although .9 of user amounts to aboyt 60 million users more thinkning is requiered

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Target version is least version of support.
If you setting 12.1 means your app will work on iOS 12.1 and above version

So , your app will not reach old iOS version users. Like iOS 11, iOS 12 and below